# Passing variables into function (MATLAB)

Tags: computer-science, matlab

I am creating a function that perform multiple regression in MATLAB. The function is created as

```
function [Beta] = george_linreg(y,x1,x2,x3,....,xN).
```

I don't know before hand how many explanatory variables there will be $\bf(x_i)$. How do I go about creating a function where any number of $\bf(x_i)$ can be inputted?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example call? It seems likely that you would be better off just passing the arguments as a vector rather than using the arbitrary number of arguments functionality.

Comment: Yes each $x$ represents a vector of values. Sorry I should have made it bold in my question!

Comment: OK. Are they the same size vectors? If so then you can just pass it as a matrix rather than using the variable argument functionality. That functionality *is* available but it is more clunky to use than you might expect.

Comment: yes but that makes using the function itself clunky. John Hughes has recommended the nargin command which looks like it will work. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) on `nargin` and `varargin`.